# random.choice only picks one option

Tags: python, python-3.x

So each time it loops it will only pick one of the options in attackword. I would like it to pick an random one each time it loops.

note: the timeout needs to stay with the %d.

```
    from threading import Timer
    import time
    import random
    import signal

    attackword = ['strike', 'damage']
    attackwords = random.choice(attackword)

    monsterhp = int(800)
    y = 150
    while monsterhp > 0:
        def TimedInput(prompt='', timeout=20, timeoutmsg=None):
            def timeout_error(*_):

                raise TimeoutError

            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_error)
            signal.alarm(timeout)
            try:
                answer = input(prompt)
                signal.alarm(0)
                return answer
            except TimeoutError:
                if timeoutmsg:
                    print(timeoutmsg)
                signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
                return None
        timeout = 4
        timeoutmsg = 'You ran out of time.'
        print(" ")
        prompt = "You have %d seconds Type %s to hit the monster\nType here: " % (timeout, attackwords)
        answer = TimedInput(prompt, timeout, timeoutmsg)

            if answer == attackwords:
                print("You strike the monster")
                time.sleep(1)
                monsterhp = monsterhp - y
                print("War Lord Health:", monsterhp)
            elif answer != attackwords and answer != None:
                print("Incorrect answer. No damage dealt.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

As you require that a copy of the word be available later on, you can assign `attackwords` inside the loop.

Add `attackwords = random.choice(attackword)` right before your `prompt` line, and leave the arguments for `prompt` as `% (timeout, attackwords)`.

The rest of your code (elif.. etc) should then work as expected, without any need for modification.

---

At present, you are assigning `attackwords` to one specific value that is returned by `random.choice()`.

To get the behaviour you desire, simply run `random.choice()` where you actually want the word to show up.

```
prompt = "You have %d seconds Type %s to hit the monster\nType here: " % (timeout, random.choice(attackword))
```

Comment: Ok that worked for one bit. I just updated the bottom part of my code. Is there a way so elif statement at the bottom will be in sync with your version you posted. Like as of now it just always checks the one word not the updated word. Thanks

Comment: Oops, did not notice that - I've updated the answer accordingly. Basically, just have your `attackwords` assignment in the loop, right before you use it. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yep it worked such a small thing. Thanks for fast response

Comment: No problem, glad to help!